# Silverlight - Exception when trying to POST to webservice

Tags: silverlight, wcf, rest

I'm using the "Post" method so I can send a custom object. But I keep getting the following exception on the request.BeginGetResponse():

{System.Net.ProtocolViolationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponseImplementation()}

```
public void Send()
    {
        HttpWebRequest client = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(BaseUrl)) as HttpWebRequest;
        client.Method = "POST";
        client.ContentLength = MaxSerializationSize;
        client.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(RequestProceed), client);
    }

    private void RequestProceed(IAsyncResult asuncResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) asuncResult.AsyncState;

        StreamWriter postDataWriter = new StreamWriter(request.EndGetRequestStream(asuncResult));
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new     DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(MyCustomClass));
        ser.WriteObject(ms, MyCustomClassObject);
        postDataWriter.Write(ms);
        postDataWriter.Close();

        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ResponceProceed), request);

    }

    private void ResponceProceed(IAsyncResult asuncResult)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest) asuncResult.AsyncState;

        using (var resp = (HttpWebResponse) request.EndGetResponse(asuncResult))
        {
            using (var stream = resp.GetResponseStream())
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tried so many ways to get this to work. Hoping someone can tell me where i'm going wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to close the request stream.  You are just closing the `StreamWriter` and not the underlying request stream.  While you are at it eliminate the superflous `MemoryStream` and have the `DataContractJsonSerializer` write directly to the Request stream.

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) asuncResult.AsyncState;

 using (Stream outStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asyncResult));
 {
      DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new     DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(MyCustomClass));           
      ser.WriteObject(outStream, MyCustomClassObject);
      outStream.Flush();
      outStream.Close();
 }

 request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ResponceProceed), request);
```

Also get rid of this line:-

```
 client.ContentLength = MaxSerializationSize;
```

Without also turning off `AllowWriteStreamBuffering` (which is only possible on the `ClientHTTP` implementation anyway) there is no need to set the `ContentLength`, that is done for you.